# Terminal output not updating display until enter key pressed

Tags: ssh

I am sshing to an Amazon instance and what I found out the display update is sloppy, sometimes the display refresh instantly but sometimes screen only updates half, eg, doing a `ls` command will only list half of the content and hangs until enter key is pressed, then it will display some more.

I am using Mac terminal if that helps to resolve this problem.

Comment: My initial suspicion is that it's client-related.  Have you tried using any other `ssh` client (from the same client to the same server), to see if the problem persists?

Comment: Same problem connecting to an Ubuntu server from a Mac and Linux host, so not client related. Persists after restarting the server. Possibly related to network quality on one or both ends of the connection?

Comment: I have the same problem but only at the office... so link related :( have your found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You may try using [mosh](http://mosh.mit.edu/) if you have connection issues

I saw also that kind of behavior after running commands with crappy output.
I usually just type `$ reset` to have my bash back.

If you're using ssh in a mac terminal I doubt it's client-related issue.
but to be sure I suggest you using screen or tmux on the server so you can dettach the session and reattach it on another client and compare outputs.